# Angular FireStore Injection erorr

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, angular-material, console

Console Angular error

[image]

My contact form didn't work. I already installed firebase. The code hasn't any errors. but after run, The code console has an error. Why does this error come? I used Angular material and bootstrap only.

I already imported firebase files in app.module.ts. this form hasn't any service file. only typescript and HTML files.

I added an Angular console error image in this post.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-us',
  templateUrl: './contact-us.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-us.component.css']
})
export class ContactUsComponent implements OnInit {

  contactForm !:FormGroup ;
  isSubmit= true;
  submitMessage = '' ;
  private myForm !: AngularFirestoreCollection <any>;

  constructor(
    private FormBuild:FormBuilder,
    private Firestore:AngularFirestore,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm=this.Firestore.collection('equiry');

    this.contactForm =this.FormBuild.group({
      name:[null,Validators.required],
      email:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.email]],
      subject:[null,Validators.required],
      message:[null,Validators.required]
    })
  }

  submitData(value:any){
    this.myForm.add(value).then(res=>{
      this.submitMessage='submit successfull...';
    }).catch(
      err=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

    console.log(value);
    this.submitMessage='submiting successfully...'
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.isSubmit=false
    },8000);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Let us help you!</h1>
    <p>If you wish to get in touch with us for bookings, queries, comments or anything else you may need, please feel free to contact us via any of the following ways:</p>
    <form [formGroup]="contactForm" class="form-group">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Your Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="name">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>E-mail</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="email">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>REASON FOR INQUIRY</mat-label>
                <mat-select  formControlName="subject">
                <mat-option value="one">Make or change reservation</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="two">wedding / Renewal of vow</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="tree">Airport tranfer</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="four">Urgent Request</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="five">General question</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="six">plan an event</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="seven">Experience / recration action</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="eight">Surfing</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="nine">Lost items</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="ten">Dinning expirence</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="eleven"> comment or feedback</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
                <textarea matInput formControlName="message"></textarea>
                
                <button mat-button color="primary" [disabled]="contactForm.invalid" (click)="submitData(contactForm.value)">Submit</button>
                <p *ngIf="isSubmit">{{submitMessage}}</p>
                
            </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for fixing the problem,
use this code in your app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebaseConfig },
  ],
```